# .Net Core Api Controller inheritance

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to create an API Module that can be used across multiple API projects. I want the Module to have a controller with an action that can be overriden based on the implementing API requirements.

I have the following project structure:

```
Module
    -Controllers
        -ModuleController.cs
    -Interfaces
        -IModel.cs
    -Models
        -Model.cs

API
    -Controllers
        -DerivedModuleController.cs
```

IModel.cs

```
public interface IModel
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Model.cs

```
public class Model : IModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

ModuleController.cs

```
[Route("api/module/[action]")]
    public class ModuleController : Controller
    {
        [ActionName("GetModel")]
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public virtual Model GetModel(int id)
        {
            return new Model() { Id = id };
        }
    }
```

DerivedModuleController.cs

```
public class DerivedModuleController : ModuleController
    {
        public override Model GetModel(int id)
        {
            return base.GetModel(id);
        }
    }
```

The API project references the Module. If I remove the DerivedModuleController everything works fine. I can make a request to `/api/module/GetModel/1` and get a valid result. However, when I add the DerivedModuleController it fails with the following error:

```
AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

Api.Controllers.DerivedModuleController.GetModel (Api)
Module.ModuleController.GetModel (Module)
```

Ultimately I want to be able to get a `DerivedModel` that extends `Model` from the `DerivedModuleController` but I can't get past this error.

Is there a way to use the base route (`/api/module/GetModel/1`) to access the DerivedModuleController and ignore the ModuleController?

Comment: that looks like some over engineering, over architecting to me, what benefits do you expect to gain by using this "module across APIs? Seems like you are just constricting APIs that inherit/implement your Module from expressing themselves

Comment: when would you have such a common Model, that your APIs extend? You models are too large and containing too much data is my impression, an API action should be simple, finite and do one thing. You can nothing much by not having to rewrite Model properties in multiple Models. Just become some of your models may have some of the same gets/setters doesn't mean inheritance is needed

Comment: @BrianOgden The benefit is that I can import the module and use it but will also have the option of implementing custom logic based on specific requirements. This is just the API part of the module, the module will contain a client side element as well that references these actions on the API. With this approach I wouldn't need to completely modify the client side in order to use the api.

Comment: I disagree with your logic,what your doing seems like you are new to RESTful api design, forgive me if I am wrong, a client, uses an API with URLs like /user or /company or /accountsummary and HTTP verbs GET, POST, PUT,DELETE, your module has nothing to do with a client, nor could a backend API module as you call it even have a client side element, if you manage for a backend API to have a client side element you are now tightly coupled and defeating the purpose of N tier architecture, perhaps consider, to stop using the word module even,you have an API here w/a controller and model

Comment: There is no solution being offered here nor is my question being answered so I don't see a point in continuing this back and forth.

Comment: Did you solve this?